# Is it haram to be pretty for someone and is it riya (showing off)?

Tags: shirk

As the question says,is it riya if someone shows off their beauty to someone? Like for example losing weight so you can get attention from people and be pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Riya which is a form of making partners with Allah (minor shirk) but not actual major shirk which is totally unforgivable and takes a person out of Islam. Minor shirk is a major sin.
But showing off or Riya means in acts of worship or good deeds like praying in public to have people see you or giving charity to the poor in front of others so they think you’re generous, or studying the Quran or Hadith in front of someone with the intention of wanting them to be impressed how religious you are. Muhammad (s) also gave the example of a man giving the adhan with the intention of wanting others to think that his voice is beautiful. Showing off with matters like trying to look pretty is not anything that has to do with Islam so this is not Riya. But we are supposed to be humble.

Prophet Muhammad (s) said in the Hadith, “The thing I fear the most for you is minor shirk.”

The Sahabas of the Prophet asked him, “What is minor shirk, Oh Messenger of Allah?” He said, “Ar-Riya. Showing off.” In one hadith the Prophet gave the example of someone making the athan (call to prayer) and while making the athan he thinks, “Wow I bet the people think my voice is beautiful.” This is ar-riyaa. In another hadith the Prophet said it’s so dangerous that it’s like the black ant on the black rock in the night with no moon. It can sneak up on you like this.

Another Hadith, “the Messenger of Allah (swt) came out to us when we were discussing the Dajjal (Anti-Christ) and said: ‘Shall I not tell you of that which I fear more for you than the Dajjal?’ We said: ‘Yes.’ He said: ‘Hidden shirk, when a man stands to pray and makes it look good because he sees a man looking at him.” (Ibn Majah 4204)

The Prophet also said that on the Day of Judgement, Allah will say, “Go to those for whom you made a show in the world and look, do you find any reward with them?”

Also it was narrated from Abu Huraira (r) said, “I heard the Messenger of Allah (swt) saying, “The first to be judged on the Day of Resurrection will be a man who died as a  shahid or a martyr. He will be brought forward. Allah will remind him of the favors he had bestowed upon him and he will acknowledge them. Then he will ask him: ‘What did you do to express gratitude for it?’ The man will reply: ‘I fought for your cause till I was martyred.’ Allah will say:’You have lied. You fought so that people might call you courageous and they have done so. Command will then be issued about him and he will be dragged on his face and thrown into hell. Next a man who had aquired and imparted knowledge and read the Qur’an will be brought forward, Allah will remind him of the he had bestowed upon him and the man will acknowledge them. Then he will ask him: ‘What did you do to express your gratitude for it?’ The man will reply: ‘I aquired knowledge and taught it and read the Quran for your sake.’ Allah will say to him: 'You have lied. You acquired knowledge so that people might call you a learned (man), and you read the Qur'an so that they might call you a reciter, and they have done so.' Command will then be issued about him, and he will be dragged on his face and thrown into Hell. Next a man whom Allah had made affluent and to whom Allah had given plenty of wealth, will be brought forward, Allah will remind him of the favours He had bestowed upon him and the man will acknowledge them. He will ask him: 'What did you do to express gratitude for it?' The man will reply: 'I did not neglect any of the ways You liked wealth to be spent liberally for Your sake'. Allah will say to him: 'You have lied. You did it so that people might call you generous, and they have done so.' Command will then be issued about him and he will be dragged on his face and thrown into Hell." (Sahih Muslim, Riyad us Saliheen 1617, Book 17, Hadith 107)

“Prophet Muhammad (s) said that Allah will not look at a man who drags his garment on the ground out of pride. And then Abu Bakr (r) said to him that sometimes his garment accidentally drags on the ground unknowingly unless he pays attention to it and the Prophet replied to him “You are not doing that out of pride.”

Prophet Muhammad (s) also said “Be humble and let none of you be arrogant toward others.”

And he said “the one who has arrogance in his heart shall not enter Paradise even if it’s the weight of a mustard seed.”

Allah (swt) says in the Quran in Surah Zumar verse 61, “ Is there not in hell an abode for the arrogant.”

Also, a woman showing her beauty to non-mahram men and exposing herself without hijab and showing awrah is haram

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

Loosing weight, makeup, getting ready and other beauty grooming activities. For all these have intention that all these are for your spouse and they will become reward for you.